# Changing between action bar tabs by clicking a common button in android

Tags: android, button, tabs, onclick, buttonclick

I have these 5 tabs and in the first tab/fragment I have a button, I want to be able to switch to another tab by clicking this button. Here's my code which contains the tabs:

```
actBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    secPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vPager.setAdapter(secPagerAdapter);

    vPager
    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    Tab tab = actBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.home)
            .setTabListener(this);
    actBar.addTab(tab, true);

    tab = actBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.cart)
            .setTabListener(this);
    actBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.users)
            .setTabListener(this);
    actBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.products)
            .setTabListener(this);
    actBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.settings)
            .setTabListener(this);
    actBar.addTab(tab);
```

This creates me a pretty nice action bar with tabs and all, and as you see the one with the home drawable has the below code:
       actBar.addTab(tab, true);
since it is true, when this activity is opened it starts with this tab. So... I have a button within this tab. When I tap this button, I want it to scroll right through to the third tab which has the users drawable as an icon. I've seen things about tabhost around here and well, if that's the 'only' case, I gotta say, I don't know about tabhost. I tried to change that `true` boolean to be able to switch between tabs `onClick` but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance. I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this inside button click listener

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(tab_position);
```

Comment: seriously... I think a tear-drop came out of my eye, how could I miss that, thanks a lot.

Comment: will do in exactly... it says 2 minutes more.